# Which hook I should use to get info about cart after payment in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I create a module. When user bought some product I want to display a special page for him. To do this I need a information about cart after payment. Which hook I should use to this ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `actionOrderStatusUpdate`.

```
public function hookActionOrderStatusUpdate($params)
{
    // You can use $params['newOrderStatus'] or $params['id_order'], i. e.:

    $order = new Order((int)$params['id_order']);

    if (Validate::isLoadedObject($order) && $order->valid)
    {
        // The order is paid, you code goes here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect the customer to a specific page instead of the standard OrderConfirmation, you can create a module and register/use the hooks `displayOrderConfirmation` or `displayPaymentReturn` in which you have the `order object` as first argument where you can check if the customer bought specific products. You also can override the `OrderConfirmationController` to modify the standard behaviour (but it's not the best practice).

Good luck